# Gridview adapter: getView() being called only 3 times when getCount() returns 9

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm working with a GridView. Basically, I ensured that getCount() returns 9, but when I debug the code, I see that getView() is only called 3 times. I don't understand why this occurs, as I clearly tell it to return 9 times.

```
public class Level1BoardAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int level;

    public Level1BoardAdapter(Context context, int level) {
        this.context = context;
        this.level = level;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 9;
    }

    @Override
    public View getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonPressed(context, level));
        com.example.titanictictactoe.Board.keys.put(position, button);
        return button;
    }

}
```

This is being called in the following class:

```
public class Level2BoardAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public Level2BoardAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 9;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GridView board = new GridView(context);
        board.setNumColumns(3);
        board.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        board.setAdapter(new Level1BoardAdapter(context, 2));
        Log.d("Count", String.format("%1d", board.getCount()));
        return board;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your array size it should be 3 otherwise it call same that you want !!

Comment: Figured it out... was just that the gridView wasn't set to a large enough height... thanks nonetheless!

Comment: if gridview get only 3 items then it show only 3.And these items comes from arraylist so, arraylist have more 3 items then get postion of all items and show in gird view, like we use jsonparsing and xml parsing check out this url http://easylearnandroid.blogspot.in/ .thanks

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` is only called when they are shown (or is being prepared to be shown) on the screen. Due to limited screen size it does not necessarily show all items. In your case your screen is able to roughly show 2 to 3 item views.

Comment: My screen can display much more... this takes up less than 1/3 of my screen

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll thro' the listview more of getView() calls should happen.
Also, i think you need to re-use your row views rather than re-creating them on each scroll. Edit `getView()` to use `convertView` parameter effectively.

Comment: This is a GridView... and scrolling through it doesn't help whatsoever